# Cannot click yes/no in MessageBox()

Tags: c, debugging, winapi, messagebox

I use a MessageBox() to confirm user actions from over a dozen different dialogs in my program.  In **ONE** of those dialogs, the MessageBox() appears but the Yes/No buttons can neither be selected via keyboard nor click by mouse. The MessageBox itself may be dragged around by the title bar and the Yes/No buttons change their highlight colors when the mouse MOVES back and forth over them, but clicks are not processed.  Even the Spy++ program shows that no CLICK messages of any kind are sent to the MessageBox at this time (but in all other times, when it works, CLICK messages are generated by clicking on the MessageBox).  All of the dialogs are created using DialogBoxParam() and all of the dialog templates have the same flags, settings, options (I have even copied all of these from a working dialog in the RC file to the problem dialog to be absolutely certain there are no different settings).

I have completely run out of ideas.  Help?

Oh, this is native C code using the Win32API without any MFC, .NET, C++ or other stuff.  (I've been writing Windows code for almost 30 years and have NEVER seen anything like this before!)

**Some answers to comments:**

- There are no message or system hooks created by the program.
- The only other threads are external communications (like TCP/IP and serial).  If they have an "event" it goes to the Windows Application Event Log
- The MessageBox() hwndParent parameter is the hwnd of the dialog that is creating them.  Always.  (But I tried using the main Window's hwnd, too and got the same result.)  Clicking (and keyboarding) is not producing any sounds from the speaker or sound system (just the physical click sounds from the mouse/keyboard itself).
- I may not have been clear, but at any given time there may be one (and only one) dialog visible and that dialog may be displaying ONE MessageBox() confirmation prompt.  For my purposes, any more would be unnecessarily confusing to the operators.

I appreciate even these questions, because I'm hoping that something, *anything* will give me the idea that helps me resolve this!  Thank you!

Final edit:

The build environment is rather complex and would require a large amount of proprietary code.  The program alone is over 75,000 lines and simple examples don't cause the problem.  In fact, 30+ other uses of the same function from other places (including dialogs) work fine.  My question was NOT for others to debug my code.  Rather, I was hoping that people might have *debugging concepts* that would help with a problem such as mine: diagnosing a built-in Windows component that is not working as expected in only one call out of many.  Apparently, Mr White et al don't believe anyone here has such knowledge, so I must give up.  Thanks to those that made an effort, I do have a few new things to think about that may help me come up with ideas of my own.

**My Solution**

Thanks to the folks who were willing to share ideas, I poked at enough different types of things to stumble over my mistake:

> I had created the problem dialog procedure as if it were a regular window rather than a dialog:  It returned the LRESULT from calling DefWindowProc() instead returning FALSE as a dialog should do.  This resulted in the very strange behavior I was seeing.

Thanks again to all those who tried.

Comment: It does seem odd.  IIRC, MessageBox(). and such dialogs, always run modally with their own OS-supplied message-loop.  Curious - have an upboat:|

Comment: Are you using any hooks (mouse, message, etc) anywhere in your program?

Comment: Does another thread create another message box and stay behind somewhere? The latest message box will gain focus.

Comment: Are any of the message boxes owned by a window from another thread? Do you get error beeps when using the keyboard or the mouse on the non-responsive dialog?

Comment: Does the observed behaviour depend on the dialogue's (the resources defining it) or on it's context (the code calling it) or on both. What happens if you instantiate the dialogue from another part of the program's code.

Comment: set `MessageBox` owner to NULL and try again. i can also suspect WM_SETFOCUS & WM_GETFOCUS, too many  possibilities that can be guessed. we hope you share a cut from your code.

Comment: @alk: The [MessageBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505.aspx) API doesn't use custom dialog resources.

Comment: by using `Spy++` you can check all window attributes and address of wndproc, are they the same with "working messagebox"?

Comment: If you're able to share your code and want to put it online in a buildable form, I'm happy to try and see if I can work out what's going on.

Comment: Questions asking *Please debug this code for me. I won't show it to you, but figure out what's wrong or at least post a list of wild speculations about what might be causing the issue* are not acceptable here. Voting to close until a MCVE is posted to demonstrate the issue, or at least the relevant portions of your code are included.

Comment: The wow64 emulator tends to be a good explanation for a problem like this, it cannot support all cases of the re-entrancy you'd get from a dialog.  Key is the trigger that causes the dialog to be displayed, a message that originates from the 64-bit window manager usually spells trouble.  Like WM_ACTIVATEAPP.  Workaround is to delay displaying the dialog so the message handling is completed by the time the dialog is displayed.  Easily done with PostMessage() to post a WM_USER message.

Comment: Thanks, but the program (in fact the whole suite of programs & DLLs) is 32 bit through and through.  I did try calling the DialogBoxParam() function directly from the main window in response to choosing Help|About from the program's menu and the problem persists.  If I remove the InitDialog code, the messagebox works there, but not if I post myself a command to try it immediately after the dialog opens.

Comment: WoW64 is short for "Windows on Windows 64". If your application is 32 bits, and it runs on a 64 bit version of Windows, you will run in the WoW64 emulation layer.